# To reverse column values

Tags: sql

I have two column given below

```
col1  col2
1      a
2      b
3      c
4      d
```

and my expected output is

```
col1    col2
1        d
2        c
3        b
4        a
```

Comment: This is highly unusual.  But tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Why bother storing data in a table if the columns are totally unrelated to each other?

Comment: Which dbms of what version you are using?

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to use subquery and self join with condition `t1.col1+t2.col1=max(col1)+min(col1)` which will enforce to have last value of t2 to be in same row with the first value of t1. But this approach will only work if you have sequential numbers without any gap in sequence.

If the number is always in proper sequence this can be faster in performance.

And another approach is with row_number(). You can have your data both in ascending and descending order then join them on their rownumber column and select col1 from ascending order and col2 from descending order.

This will be better approach if your dbms supports this, since any gap in the sequence is accepted here.

Schema:

> ```
> create table test (col1 int,  col2 varchar(10));
> insert into test values(1     , 'a');
> insert into test values(2     , 'b');
> insert into test values(3     , 'c');
> insert into test values(4     , 'd');
> ```

Query#1 with subquery and self join:

```
 select t1.col1, t2.col2
 from test t1 join
      test t2
      on t1.col1 + t2.col1 =(select max(col1)+min(col1) from test)
 order by t1.col1
```

Output:

| col1 | col2 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | d |
| 2 | c |
| 3 | b |
| 4 | a |

Query#2 with row_number()over():

```
 select t1.col1,t2.col2 from
 (select col1,col2,row_number()over(order by col1)rn from test)t1
 inner join (select col1,col2,row_number()over(order by col1 desc)rn from test)t2
 on t1.rn=t2.rn
```

output:

| col1 | col2 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | d |
| 2 | c |
| 3 | b |
| 4 | a |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=2fbfa7dc93b4684e1907a7a8920648bd)*

Answer (score 0):

For your given data, you can use a self-join:

```
select t.col1, t2.col2
from t join
     t t2
     on t2.id = 5 - t.id ;
```

This does not generalize particularly well.